# Use Excel VBA to change the value of a cell in a closed workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

I currently use this function in VBA to get the value of a cell in a closed workbook. I want to use a similar process to SET the value of the cell to whatever I want, without opening the file. Is that possible?

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)

    Dim arg As String
    If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
        GetValue = "File Not Found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
        Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)
    GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

Comment: Consider using **ADO**  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278973

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can do this using ADO as Gary commented but only if your Excel Worksheet is arranged in a Database like structure.
Meaning you have valid fields arranged in columns (with or without headers).
For example:

[image]

Now, you see that ID number **12345** have a name *John John* and you want to update it to *John Knight*.
Using ADO you can try:

**Edit1:** You can actually do this without using *Recordset*. See below update.

```
Sub conscious()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sqlstr As String, datasource As String

    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    datasource = "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\TestDataBase.xlsx" 'change to suit

    Dim sconnect As String
    sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & datasource & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"

    With con
        .Open sconnect
        sqlstr = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [Name] = ""John Knight"" WHERE [ID Number] = 12345"
        .Execute sqlstr
        .Close
    End With

    Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want but HTH.

**Notes:**

1. You need to add reference to *Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects X.X Library* (early bind).
2. But you can also do this using late bind (no reference).
3. Connection string used is for Excel 2007 and up.
4. **Sheet1** is the name of the target sheet you want to update the value to.

**Edit1:** This is how to do it if your file have no header

First change the connection string *HDR* argument to **NO**:.

```
sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "Data Source=" & datasource & ";" & _
           "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO"";"
```

Then adjust your SQL string to:

```
sqlstr = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET F2 = ""John Knight"" WHERE F1 = 12345"
```

So that is `F1` for *field 1*, `F2` for *field 2* etc.