# Write in closed workbook not organized in fields

Tags: vba, excel

I found this question in here : [Use Excel VBA to change the value of a cell in a closed workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908561/use-excel-vba-to-change-the-value-of-a-cell-in-a-closed-workbook)
and the answer was for sheets organized like databases (columns organized like fields).

So I am asking myself if it is possible to update a cell in closed workbook even if the sheet is not organized. Say, for example, update the cell A1.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Create a new hidden excel application instance, open the closed workbook, update sheet1!a1, close and save changes.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! It works!