# Change a cell of a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I try to change the cell "A6" of a different workbook, so I wrote this code but it doesn't work I don't know why, I tried different code but it still doesn't work, do you know why ?

Thank you

```
 Sub test()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim shCurrency As Worksheet
    Set wbSource = Workbooks("BP19.xls")
    Set shCurrency = wbSource.Sheets("KPI")

       wbSource.shCurrency.Range("A6") = "LC"

End Sub
```

But it work when I put this

```
 Workbooks("BP19.xls").Worksheets("KPI").Range("A6") = "EUR"
```

Comment: get rid of the `wbSource` in front of `shCurrency`. `shCurrency` already refers to a `Sheet` in `wbSource`.

Comment: Neither way will work if the workbook isn't **open**.  A clue is that the filename does not have a path... but even still this method won't work a closed workbook.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27914490/8112776

Comment: Thank you BigBen ! it's been two hours since I was stuck on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `wbSource` in front of `shCurrency`. `shCurrency` already refers to a `Sheet` in `wbSource`.

```
Sub test()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim shCurrency As Worksheet
    Set wbSource = Workbooks("BP19.xls")
    Set shCurrency = wbSource.Sheets("KPI") 

    shCurrency.Range("A6") = "LC" 

End Sub
```